# From request redirecting to same page (not working). laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using from request named StoreAdminRequest to validate my form but nothing is happening. It redirects to the same page. I can't figure out whats wrong. However when I dd in rules() function it does enter in that function.

> StoreAdminRequest.php

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\Admin;

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;


/**
 * Class StoreAdminRequest.
 */
class StoreAdminRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        // return access()->hasRoles([2,6]);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
                'first_name'     => 'required|max:191',
                'last_name'  => 'required|max:191',
                'email'    => 'required', 'email', 'max:191', Rule::unique('users','email'),
                'mobile'  => 'required'
            ];
    }

}
```

> AdminController.php

```
public function store(StoreAdminRequest $request)
    {
        $admin = $this->_admin->create($request->all());
    }
```

Comment: your form doesn't pass the validation and is redirected back, check the errors in the session

Comment: That is expected behavior as it is not supposed to proceed and if you want to see the errors check the errors variable and if you still are confused pass values that pass the validation and then check what happens

Comment: ok, thanks guys my bad. I needed to loop through the $errors variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to loop through the $errors variable. thanks

```
@if ($errors->any())
       <div class="alert alert-danger">
           <ul>
               @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
               @endforeach
           </ul>
       </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: Please leave an explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to redirect to a different route you should use

```
return redirect()->route('/desired/route/to/redirect');
```

in your Controller.

Your actual problem is caused by a missing RedirectResponse to change the desired page you get from the server. If no other route is defined, you will always get redirected to the page you made the request.